# Do realistic, human-like androids exist in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, droids, androids

Do androids — as we commonly conceive them — exist in the Star Wars universe?

Meaning, droids that are convincingly life-like and sentient and can pass for humans, rather than robots with bipedal/anthropomorphic characteristics (*The Glove of Darth Vader* series faux-Leia marriage excluded…)

Comment: Data from Star Trek, Replicants from Blade Runners... yes, you get the idea. Thank you for the clarity edit

Comment: Wookieepedia has a whole page dedicated to this topic, but it is all Legends, not Canon. https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Human_replica_droid

Comment: All, "androids" in SW are pretty much humans in metal can. If you put some fake skin on C3PO how could you tell if he isn't some well educated slave?

Comment: Do the Marvel Star Wars comics from the '70s count as canon? After they'd done the adaptation of A New Hope, and moved on to their own stories, there was one with a bounty hunter that looked human and turned out to be an android.

Comment: @Brian Nothing that old, except the original movie trilogy obviously, is canon.  Very little before the Disney purchase is still cannon (basically the movies and the Clone Wars cartoon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legends featured [fully human-looking androids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Human_replica_droid). Perhaps the most well-known was [Guri](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Guri) from *Shadows of the Empire*.

[image]

In canon, we have not yet seen a fully human-looking droid. However, I argue that the technology for it is there. Luke's robotic hand looks fully organic, meaning the technology could theoretically be applied to a full individual.

[image]

Comment: And yet, forty years later, his hand looked very robotic.  Wore out the skin, I guess (yeah, I know, CGI for a metal hand in a bunch of shots in the next movie didn't exist yet when *Empire* came out).